Text in DropdownMenuItem is not visible

I'm developing an application in Kotlin. The text inside my ComboBox is not visible if I don't assign a color, and it is also not visible in dark mode. Is there a simple solution for this without setting a color?
@Composable // Composable function // Composable fonksiyon // UnitConverter function // UnitConverter fonksiyonu
fun UnitConverter(
    name: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), // Fill the entire screen (width and height) // Ekranın tamamını doldur (genişlik ve yükseklik)
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, // Center the content vertically,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, // Center the content horizontally // İçeriği yatay olarak ortalayın
        // İçeriği dikey olarak ortalayın
    ) {
        Text("Unit Converter") // Text // Metin
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(value = "", onValueChange = {
            // TODO
        })

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Row {
            Box {
                Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    // Button // Düğme
                    Text("Select")
                    Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "Arrow Down")
                }
                DropdownMenu(expanded = true, onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Centimeters", color = Color.Black) }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Meters", color = Color.Black) }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Feet", color = Color.Black) }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("MiliMeters", color = Color.Black) }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                }
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            Box {
                Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text("Convert")
                    Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "Arrow Down")
                }

                DropdownMenu(expanded = true, onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { "ss" }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Meters", color = Color.Black) }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Feet", color = Color.Black) }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("MiliMeters", color = Color.Black) }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                }
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Text("Result")
    }
}

Text default color black

Why haven't you wrapped ss inside a Text component? Also, have you added a material theme to your app?

It's because of color. You didn't add color property. Even if you add color = Color.Black, It is also not visible in dark mode because of the static color. Use MaterialColor instead of Color.Black.
color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
